# Is it possible to set up MongoDB in a shared hosting environment?

Tags: mongodb, daemon

I'm using GoDaddy and would like to use MongoDB for a pet project.
I'm not sure it is possible though, since it has to be running the daemon, but, it doesn't hurt to ask, is there a way?

EDIT: 
They've closed the question, but if anybody stumbles upon this post with the same question:

While you cannot set up MongoDB in a traditional share environment, thanks to the magic of the Cloud you can now find Free Mongo Hosting in places like:

https://mongolab.com/welcome/

https://www.mongohq.com/home

https://manage.windowsazure.com (via mongolab)

Comment: Excellent qns man.. May i know how's your progress? Did you managed to setup a website that runs on mongodb? I have gotten my localhost website to connect to the MongoHQ database, now i still need to find a web host where i can install the php extension driver and edit the php.ini..

Comment: @p0larBoy unfortunately no... As the accepted answer said.. there is no way to set up the daemon in Go Daddy (or pretty much any hosted solution), and I wasnt willing to pay extra to have the DB hosted separately... and since it was just a pet project and playing with technologies it wasnt so imporant, so in short nop, i didnt manage to get it to run, thou still tried it locally and its pretty fun

Comment: how about running your own dedicated server using ubuntu server and virtual box? good enough for a pet project right?

Comment: Just find a share hosting that provieds you with mongodb and other goodies. There are many out there.

Comment: @DevWL Can you please share the name for such hosting? I need it

Comment: @Shyam Just type in google "shared hosting with mongodb", you should aim the hosting in your location. PS. You can also use the external MongoDB database (AZURE - free 500MB or AWS) with any hosting. Both PHP and node.js have libraries for that - but not every hosting has node.js and mongodb on it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there'd be no way to install and run it if you are only using shared hosting account. You would need the ability to log on and make changes.

However, you could always look into alternatives like using an external MongoDB hosted service such as [MongoHQ](https://app.mongohq.com/home). That way, you can still use MongoDB. The downside is that you'll most likely end up having to pay more for the service.

Comment: that's what I thought... sigh.. well thanks for the hosted mongo tip, i didnt know they did that :D

Comment: list of mongodb hosting servers- http://cloudhostingguru.com/mongoDB-server-hosting.php

Comment: that list no longer works

Answer (score 2):

The link mention above (http://schweitzertech.com/wordpress/uncategorized/setting-up-mongodb-with-godaddy-hosting/) does not help in this particular case. This is not what the poster is looking for.  This lets you run mongodb on the command line only.  For production purposes, they would need to be able to edit the php.ini and add the mongodb php module, which you can not do on shared hosting.  So, at this time, you can not use mongodb for a website on shared hosting.